# Number of discontinuous points related problem

Tags: limits

[image]
If $f\left( x \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{{\left( {\cos x} \right)}^{2n}}}&{x < 0}\\
{{{\left( {1 + {x^n}} \right)}^{\frac{1}{n}}}}&{0 \le x \le 1}\\
{\frac{1}{{1 + {x^n}}}}&{x > 1}
\end{array}} \right.$ then number of points where f(x) is discontinuous is ________

My approach is as follow

Checking the continuity at $x=1$

$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left\{ {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {1^ + }} \frac{1}{{1 + {x^n}}}} \right\} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left\{ {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{{1 + {{\left( {1 + h} \right)}^n}}}} \right\} = 0$

I am not able to proceed with the left hand side continuity at x=1

Comment: For x=1 that looks suspiciously like Euler's number

Comment: Added the picture of the problem so that to avoid any confusion

Comment: You can't freely change the order of the limits. You need the innermost limit to be $n\to\infty$

Comment: The function is not continuous at x=1, right hand limit is Euler's number, left hand is 0